# How do I find the volume of this square pyramid and also the base edge.

Tags: geometry

How do I find the volume of a square pyramid? Diagonal length is 4cm and the height is 3cm

[image]

[Grade 9 Math]

Comment: Do you know the formula for the volume of a pyramid?

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a pyramid is given by $$V=\frac{lwh}3$$ where $l$ and $w$ are the lengths of the sides of the base and $h$ is the height

We know that our base is square, so $l=w$ and we can therefore see the following

```
   w 
 ------
|\     |
| \    |
|  \4  | w
|   \  |
|    \ |
 ------
```

We can use Pythagoras' theorem to find $w$:

\begin{align}w^2+w^2&=4^2\\
2w^2&=16\\
w^2&=8\\
w&=\sqrt8\\
&=2\sqrt 2\end{align}

Now we can use the formula from above to find the volume:

\begin{align}V&=\frac{lwh}3\\
&=\frac{w^2h}3\\
&=\frac{(2\sqrt 2)^2\times 3}3\\
&=\frac{8\times3}3\\
&=8\text{ cm}^3\end{align}